# How do I position/size objects inside an Android jetpack compose Box by percent?

Tags: android

I'm just starting with Android jetpack compose and would like to place a button in a Box and have the button be 20% as wide as the width of the Box and have it be 50% of the width of the Box.  In the old ContraintLayout, I could do this with layout_constraintGuide_percent.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can set the width and height with respect to parent like this,

```
Button(modifier = Modifier.
       fillMaxWidth(0.5f)) //50% width as the parent
```

Comment: does the parent of that component max width??

Comment: but how not fill it if the content make take less then 50%? need something like `.widthIn(min, max)` but with percentages instead of dp

Comment: same here... @user924 did you already find a solution?

Comment: @swalkner for now I do custom calculation: `Modifier.onSizeChanged { parentWidth = with(density) { it.width.toDp() } }` at your container and then you can use it like this `Modifier.widthIn(max = parentWidth  * 0.75f)` for elements inside container